# How can I *safely* edit totally broken new user's question?

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users

So, it's happened again. Some user posted *valid* question with invalid formatting and grammar, not mentioning the totally useless title "Please help 139 return value C".

So I start editing the question. That involves figuring out good title based on actual context, adding punctuation and breaking sentences into shorter ones (I always wonder why users with poor grammar make those endless sentences) and also adding proper code indentation, instead of quote block or one-line backticks that the user used.

Half through the edit, message pops out "*This question has been edited, please click to load*". Usually, the only change is fix to the formating by some 1k+ rep user. Sometimes it's worse, for example they change one or two most obvious errors. Then, I have to make a diff between the two posts. Of course, only unless I accidentally forgot to copy my edit into text editor.

What can I do to avoid this discomfort while editing posts?

Comment: Nothing, really, I'm afraid (except maybe for saving often in between edits). Locking has been discussed and rejected, multiple times I think.

Comment: Other than waiting at least until the question is 15 minutes old before you do any substantial edit, I don't think there is any way you're going to prevent concurrency problems. Conversationally: should you really care? The important thing is that the best edit ends up on top, and in this scenario that is likely yours.

Comment: @Gimby It's tedious to make manual diff-merge between edits. Even worse if the OP adds/changes something.

Comment: I've started following the 10-15 minute rule @Gimby mentioned, or at least until it starts getting enough upvotes that it won't get deleted automatically.